# Start process as administrator from IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I need to start a process (.exe console application) as Administrator user from a WCF Service hosted in IIS7 (Windows Server 2008). How can get this?

thank you,
Riccardo

Comment: Just an opinion, but rather than try to find a way to let the IIS/WCF service run as administrator, why not appropriately permission the IIS user to perform the tasks required by the console application?

Comment: how can I set this permissions? thank you

Comment: Well, what is it that your console app is doing that fails under the IIS user? Unless it's installing something, it may be failing for trying to write to a location or a file on which it does not have write permissions. If so, you'll need to edit that resource and grant permissions to the IIS user (or the group that the IIS user belongs to--better approach if that's how your system is set up).

Comment: This console apps run a proprietary dll, but i don't know what exactly try to do. If I run this app manually (administrator user) it works fine.

Comment: But a dll isn't really anything special :-) If you have read permission on the folder and execute permission on the dll, I think that should be fine. If you can try running the console app from the service and see where it fails, that will tell you if it's this dll or something else.

Comment: On the folder there is "everyone" full control, but it doesn't works. I think that this library try to access to capture devices or do something that requires administrative privileges. In the log of this dll I see only this sensless error: "library not found: v~f".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a WCF service in IIS, however for a basic website, you click on the site (in inetmgr IIS7) and under the IIS section there is an icon called Authentication. Then there are several options in the main box like Anonymous Authentication, etc. Select one and then on the right side hit the edit button. You can specify the user you want the site to execute with. You could select your admin account if you really wanted to.

Again, this is for an IIS website, not WCF service.

Like some of the other commentators say though, giving it a full admin account isn't the right way to go though. I'd create a limited user account w/ the bare minimum privileges.

Comment: Yes, you right. Infact I have in my application (or WCF service) "anonymous" authentication with "administrator" user, but I see in the task manager that my console app is started as "ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" user and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the application identity of the pool (in the advanced settings). This is not the final solution, but for now it works.